# caret and dollar sign doesn't work in scrapy s

Tags: regex, scrapy

I am trying to use regular expression to extract data from a selector. But I find caret and dollar sign doesn't work as I expected.

I was using .* to test the ^ and $ sign as below. I thought two lines below should return the same thing.

But the first one just returns an empty list. And the second one returns the entire block as I expected.

```
response.xpath('//script[contains(.,"reports")]/text()').re('^.*$')

response.xpath('//script[contains(.,"reports")]/text()').re('.*')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*` is not including new lines and line breaks.

`^` Matches the beginning of the string, or the beginning of a line if the multiline flag is set.

Same for `$` - end of string or end of line in multiline flag is set.

For better testing try `^[\s\S]*$` expression. This will include any symbols in between of string start and string end.